# Iterate over object coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

How do I iterate through the keys in an object to display the key and values associated with it? Say the hash is the following:

```
hash =
a: 'b'
c: 'd'
e: 'f'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
for k, v of hash
    console.log('%s %s', k, v)
```

Answer (score 18):

```
for key, value of hash
    console.log "#{key} = #{value}"
```